# Automatic correcting line wrap in TexLipse NOT at certain lines

Tags: eclipse

I'm using the texlipse plugin of eclipse to edit my tex-files. In this plugin there's the nice feature to autocorrect line wrap or in the latex menu "Correct Line Wrap". So far, so good. But now I don't want the line wrapping be "corrected" in lstlisting areas... I type there some bash code for example and I don't want the text to be "corrected" there. Is it possible to cogfigure this?

```
\subsubsection{My title}
Correct the line wrap of this text Correct the line wrap of this text
Correct the line wrap of this text Correct the line wrap of
this text Correct the line wrap of this text
% DONT CORRECT THE LINE WRAP OF THE FOLLOWING lstlisting
\begin{lstlisting}
adp-get install ant
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wrapping text](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/wrapping.html) documentation, TeXlipse supports a hard wrap function to the selected text area :

> To use this feature, the user must
>   first select the area and then press
>   Esc Q or select Latex > Correct Line
>   Wrap.

I believe that is as far your options go.

For more than that, you will need to either do the necessary development to the [sources](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/release.html), or go on the [TeXlipse forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/forums) and convince the developers that this is a good idea.

Comment: I feared something like that... I'll try to convince them, thank you :-)

Comment: Oh ok, sorry! Didn't know that. Have you received the 50 points?

Comment: Yes, glad to have been of help.